# Email catch all (domain and subdomains) Postfix

Tags: centos, postfix

I just want to catch all email sent to * @domain.com AND * @ * .domain.com to a unique email system@domain.Com

@runlevel6
Any idea to implement regexp in virtual like

```
cat /etc/postfix/virtual 
@example.com system@example.com 
/[@*].example.com$/ system@example.com
```

I found it:

in main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual-sub
```

in virtual-sub

```
/[@.]example\.tld$/ sure@example.tld
```

thx runlevel6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix supports the use of a catchall account using the luser_relay configuration option.

See the postfix page for [luser_relay](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#luser_relay) for more information.

> When the local(8) delivery agent finds
>   that a message recipient does not
>   exist, the message is normally
>   returned to the sender ("user
>   unknown"). Sometimes it is desirable
>   to forward mail for non-existing
>   recipients to another machine. For
>   this purpose you can specify an
>   alternative destination with the
>   luser_relay configuration parameter.

If it is not a catchall for all domains on the server you can instead user Virtual Aliases.  See the postfix page for [virtual aliases](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) for more information.  Short description and code excerpt from that page are as follows:

> With virtual alias domains, each
>   hosted address is aliased to a local
>   UNIX system account or to a remote
>   address. The example below shows how
>   to use this mechanism for the
>   example.com domain.

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
virtual_alias_domains = example.com ...other hosted domains...
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
postmaster@example.com postmaster
info@example.com       joe
sales@example.com      jane
# Uncomment entry below to implement a catch-all address
@example.com           jim
...virtual aliases for more domains...
```

After making those changes, run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` and `postfix reload`.

**EDIT:** I think the regexp that you are looking for is `/[@.]example\.com$/ system`

You might need to make additional changes in main.cf to support this.  See [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/postfix-virtual-wildcard-subdomains-691877/) for more information.

Comment: thx will try it now.

Comment: Any idea to implement regexp in virtual like

cat /etc/postfix/virtual
@example.com system@example.com
/[@*].example.com$/ system@example.com

Comment: post updated with regexp and a link to a post on LinuxQuestions.org that has more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the settings to do a catch-all, but to an external server (I use this server as my smarthost for dev machines).

- Replace mail.example.com with your server (we use exchange)
- Replace devteam@example.com with your destination for all emails that are
  sent to this box.
- Replace the 192.168.0.0 network with your dev
  network

```
postconf -e recipient_canonical_classes=envelope_recipient
postconf -e recipient_canonical_maps=regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_map
postconf -e mynetworks=192.168.0.0/24
postconf -e header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
postconf -e relayhost=mail.example.com
```

cat /etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_map

```
/./ devteam@example.com
```