# Postfix CatchAll Except local domains

Tags: postfix

I'd like to expand on my existing catch-all (from answer)
[Email catch all (domain and subdomains) Postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/161321/email-catch-all-domain-and-subdomains-postfix/726064#726064)

So emails to *@example.com are delivered to *@example.com
but emails to *@gmail.com are redirected to CatchAll@example.com

```
/./ CatchAll@example.com
```

Maybe something like?

```
!/.example.com CatchAll@example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with

```
!/example\.com|example\.org/ devcatchall@example.com
```

Which would allow local delivery, but catch any attempts to send outside.